# Why is my activity causing memory leak when navigating away with home button?

Tags: android

Whenever I navigate away from my app with the Home button on my Android phone and enter the app again using the launcher icon, the initial activity of my app duplicates. If I repeat the routine five times, there are five instances of my initial activity.

I have monitored this through heap dumps in Eclipse, making sure I garbage collect before each dump. This is the view I get when I ask for *Merge Shortes Path to GC Root with all references* of my activity class in the histogram view:

```
Class Name                                                                     | Ref. Objects | Shallow Heap | Ref. Shallow Heap | Retained Heap
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                                               |              |              |                   |              
android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver @ 0x41408a80 Native Stack   |            1 |           32 |               224 |           184
class android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager @ 0x40d93e78 System Class    |            1 |           88 |               224 |           616
'- mInstance android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager @ 0x413422e0          |            1 |          112 |               224 |           296
   '- mServedView, mNextServedView android.widget.ListView @ 0x41331100        |            1 |        1 088 |               224 |       124 096
      '- mContext nilsnett.chinese.activities.GameOverviewActivity @ 0x44eeecd8|            1 |          224 |               224 |         1 000
android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver @ 0x41af4a60 Native Stack   |            1 |           32 |               224 |           184
android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver @ 0x412cf928 Native Stack   |            1 |           32 |               224 |           184
android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver @ 0x44cd3090 Native Stack   |            1 |           32 |               224 |           184
'- this$0 android.view.ViewRootImpl @ 0x44cd1f20                               |            1 |          464 |               224 |         2 168
   '- mView com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView @ 0x44cbef00|            1 |          536 |               224 |         1 336
      '- mContext nilsnett.chinese.activities.GameOverviewActivity @ 0x44cbdee8|            1 |          224 |               224 |         1 000
Total: 5 entries                                                               |            5 |          216 |             1 120 |              
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So it seems like there is a property (or class?) `WindowInputEventReceiver` that is keeping reference to my activity `GameOverviewActivity`. Why, and how do I stop it?

Comment: What happens if you specify `android:singleInstance="true"` in your manifest?

Comment: Check the Inent Flags you are setting when starting the Activity... This is an abnormal behavior some leaky code must be there...

Comment: Do you have any visible dialogs when you press home button ??

Comment: @Amit There is a splash screen activity that starts it with startActivity(new Intent(this, GameOverviewActivity.class));

Comment: @aleks-g : If you mean android:launchMode="singleInstance": That worked like a charm! I will definitely use that for my app. BUT, I'm not satisfied with this as the answer for the original question - it's not really supposed to leak activities in that manner whenever people DONT'T use the option, right?

Comment: @rachita-nanda : No. It's a standard ListActivity with a couple of buttons and a ListView.

Comment: First, yes, that's what I meant `launchMode="singleInstance"`.  There's a bit more information about launch modes on [android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html) site, but not too much.  Normally, you would declare your main launch activity as single instance and the rest of activities without it - at least, that's how I've been doing it.

Comment: @AleksG that's how I've been doing it too...

Comment: And that's how I'll do it to, but I don't like how Google writes in big red letters in their documentation "The other modes — singleTask and singleInstance — are not appropriate for most applications"

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=34731

Answer (score -2):

I found the reason is `WindowInputEventReceiver` implements the finalize method，it cause  a reference. I call `System.gc` in `onDestroy` to solve this problem.